# Front face camera android.

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am developing a demo in which I have to check if device has front camera if device has front camera then I have to open it to capture a image.

I searched a lot but didn't find any solution. Please help me by giving a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My solution for use front face camera :

```
private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx<cameraCount; camIdx++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Your_TAG", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return cam;
}
```

Complete tutorial for use camera -> [**HERE**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html)

And my result in picture :

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but i tried this code and its not working for me.

Comment: you must have another problem. Directs you to this tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, let me try this link.

Comment: can you please send me your demo project if you don't mind on my mail id "tryngbgud.rahul@gmail.com"

Comment: This is a big project, but do not worry I'll send you the files you need :) @rahul

Comment: I just sent you a working project on the use of the camera.

Comment: Can you send me the example too? I am having troubles to make this work. Thanks

Comment: I will create an open source project on GitHub. I would leave a comment when it is filed with the link.

Comment: @lopez.mikhael i try your code but gives error unable to connect to camera service.Can you please help me.what the error is?

Comment: @lopez.mikhael you could upload the code? thanks!

Comment: The code in this answer looks, to the casual observer at least, essentially the same as the code posted in the question. Please explain in what way this _answers_ the question. I.e. the OP says the code they posted doesn't work, the answer seems to simply claim it does work. What's different?

Comment: @Peter: OP edited it afterwards in, see edit history.